# Automating Bootstrap dropdown using Selenium java

Tags: selenium, automation, dropdown

Below is the code of bootstrap drop-down. After selecting any value from the drop down the tick mark '✓' is also getting selected.

```
<ul style="max-height:48px;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;" aria-expanded="false" aria-activedescendant="item1520752761987-1" aria-label="Select your size" title="Select your size" role="listbox" tabindex="0">
    <li id="item1520752761987-1" class="selected" role="option" style="width: 52px;">
    --
    <span class="checked" aria-hidden="true"> ✓</span>
    </li>
    <li id="item1520752761987-2" role="option" data-value="248" style="width: 52px;">7</li>
    <li id="item1520752761987-3" role="option" data-value="304" style="width: 52px;">8</li>
    <li id="item1520752761987-4" role="option" data-value="306" style="width: 52px;">9</li>
    <li id="item1520752761987-5" role="option" data-value="278" style="width: 52px;">10</li>
    <li id="item1520752761987-6" role="option" data-value="280" style="width: 52px;">11</li>
    <li id="item1520752761987-7" role="option" data-value="282" style="width: 52px;">12</li>
    <li id="item1520752761987-8" role="option" data-value="284" style="width: 52px;">13</li>
    <li id="item1520752761987-9" role="option" data-value="285" style="width: 52px;">14</li>
    <li id="item1520752761987-10" role="option" data-value="286" style="width: 52px;">15</li>
    </ul>
```

Unable to select values from the drop down.
Below, is the selenium Java code that i used.

```
List<WebElement> dd_menu=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@title='Select your size']//li"));
    for(int i=0;i<dd_menu.size();i++)
    {
        WebElement element=dd_menu.get(i);
        String val=element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
        if(val.contentEquals("11"))
        {
            element.click();
        }
        //System.out.println("Values From Dropdown : "+val);
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='product-addtocart-button']")).click();
}
```

The above selenium java code for clicking bootstrap dropdown did not work...i need help

Getting the error message in eclipse given below:

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class='checked']//parent::li[@id='item1520579060429-1']"}
Command duration or timeout: 48 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
System info: host: 'VG-IT-LAP-104', ip: '192.168.1.100', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//span[@class='checked']//parent::li[@id='item1520579060429-1']}
Session ID: 2ca11707-7e86-4811-a76b-b7461d3dfb92
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=33.0.3}]

Tried different combination of dynamic xpaths given below, but still did not work:

```
//li[contains(@id,'item1520491614103-8')]//following::span[@class='checked']
//li[contains(.,'13')]
//span[@class='checked']//parent::li[@id='item1520579060429-1']
```

Can you please guide me where it went wrong..if my xpath is incorrect to select any value from the drop down..please advise with a correct xpath

Comment: Please elaborate on *This code did not work*. What **exactly** is the problem?

Comment: Add the error stack stacktrace also. This code did not work is a very vague and abstract statement.

Comment: Now, i have included the error that I am facing right now and also the dynamic xpaths that i have used so far

Comment: I think the Xpath in your code is the best, better then the alternatives you give. To find out if it's timing issue add a Thread.Sleep(5000) before your first statement in the code block above. When timing is indeed the problem replace the sleep by an explicitwait in your final code.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for you suggestion, tried it but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

As per your code you have used the following *Locator Strategy* :

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@title='Select your size']//li"));
```

But you are seeing an error as :

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element
```

I don't see any error as such in your code block however your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **2.45.0** of **2015-03-05 22:01:35** which is *3 years* older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.7.0_79** which is *ancient*.

So there is a clear mismatch between the current *JDK* version (*8u162*) and the current *Selenium Client* version (*v10.0.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) level.
- Upgrade *Selenium Client* to  [**10.0.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) level.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Browser* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of the *Web Browser*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your suggesstion, i followed as per your comment, upgraded the Selenium version and java version, but still facing the same issue. Please see the error log given below

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='item1520927444953-1']"}  (Session info:chrome=65.0.3325.146)  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows 
Build info: version: '3.10.0', revision: '176b4a9', time: '2018-03-02T19:10:56.039Z'System info: host: 'VG-IT-LAP-104', ip: '172.20.23.27', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

```
for(int i=0;i<dd_menu.size();i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=1;i<dd_menu.size();i++)
```

Based on your error message, it is attempting to access the first list item which is actually a hidden entry (the check mark).  By starting your loop at zero instead of one, you are including that list item.  If the rest of your code is correct, skipping that item should work, or at least produce a different error.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your suggestion, i changed the code as per your comment, but still facing the same issue. any other suggestions please

Comment: Are you sure the error message did not change?  Because it was specifically referring to the first (0) element in the original.  Does it still refer to that same element?

Comment: Yes, error message did not change, the same no such element found exception came in the error message.

Comment: <li id="item1520927444953-1" class="selected" role="option" style="width: 52px;">
--
<span class="checked" aria-hidden="true"> ✓</span>
</li>       this is the element i am trying to click

Comment: Is it something to do with 'aria-hidden'=true in the <span> tag ?